# Can my additional / part time job be included as "other income" in the UK visa application form?

Tags: visas, uk, applications

in the section **Do you have savings, properties or other income, for example from stocks and shares?**

Can my additional / part time job stand as 'other income? If Yes, what will the total income be monthly? my part-time job is not frequent as I do that when my clients need my service.

Payment is made in my salary account. I have about 4 credits for the past 6 months. In my cover letter, I have given a detailed breakdown of all these additional income inflows into my account.

Thank you for your advice

Comment: You are not saying why and to whom you need to proof your income.

Comment: In the application form. I have edited my question. Thanks

Comment: If you can prove the source of the credits eg via invoices to your clients, tax return etc you can include the income. If it’s irregular, just divide the total received by the number of months and explain the calculation in your covering letter. If the amount is very small including it might not make much difference to your chances of success

Comment: @TorstenS the asker did tag the question as being a UK visa application

Comment: @Traveller I have invoices for the payment but didnt make tax returns as its just a personal side hobby.  The total amount of credit in my account for the period of six month is 200,000 Naira (410 Pounds) while my full-time salary credited every month is 260,000 Naira ( 530 Pounds) .

Comment: Why would this not go down in the "normal" income box? I'm sure the notes provided with the form would clarify, your situation here isn't unusual.

Comment: @AndyT I have declared my full time job but at this section i dont know what do put. Should i just say 'NO'

Comment: @olowogbo - I don't have the notes (provided with the form) with me to read them. You should have them. I would suspect that all earned income would go in the same box: "normal income". This "other income" box sounds like it is asking about unearned income. The one thing I would no do is to not declare this income somewhere on the form.

Comment: If the income is not regular, you should mention it as you have done, but the visa officer will probably discount it.  You could calculate a monthly average and include it in the "other income" box, but you should be very explicit about that if you do it, to avoid the appearance of deception.  If your salary is sufficient by itself to support your application, I would suggest not claiming the income at all beyond the mention you have made in the cover letter.  If you do that, explain in the cover letter that you didn't include it on the form because it is sporadic.

Comment: @phoog this is the only thing that is stopping me from submitting my application.  I was refused in January 2018, because of the additional income in my account which wasn't declared. Is it fine i mention it in my cover letter and put 'NO' in the form.???

Comment: @olowogbo my opinion isn't very authoritative. If you can afford it, you should consider seeking help from a UK immigration lawyer.

Comment: @phoog So i cant get help here?

Comment: Here you can get opinions from people who may not be qualified to give them, which may or may not be correct. In light of your relatively recent refusal (and the reason you say was behind it), I would proceed with caution. It would be especially incautious to rely on advice from anyone who has not read your prior refusal notice. Perhaps you can post a redacted image of it here.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments/questions.  Putting on hold for now.